# How do I pass multiple optional arguments from custom command to function?

Tags: functions, command, argument-list

Given a function with two optional arguments

```
fun s:foo(one = v:false, two = v:false)
  echom '<' . a:one . ',' . a:two . '>'
endf
```

and a custom `command` calling it

```
command! -nargs=* Foo call s:foo()
```

how do I pass arguments from `:Foo` to `s:foo`?

I thought that `<args>` would be useful, but it doesn't do what I expected.

1. If I go for `command! -nargs=* Foo call s:foo(<args>)`, then

   - `:Foo` gives `<v:false,v:false>`, which is what I expect, both args are being defaulted;
   - `:Foo v:true` gives `<v:true,v:false>`, again what I expect, with the first arg being given and the second defaulted;
   - `:Foo v:true v:true` **results in an error: `E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>3_foo`**.
2. If I go for `command! -nargs=* Foo call s:foo('<args>')`, then things are definitely worse:

   - `:Foo` gives `<,v:false>` revealing that `<args>` is `''` passed to `one`, while `two` uses the default;
   - `:Foo v:true` gives `<v:true,v:false>`, revealing that `<args>` is `v:true`, while `two` uses the default;
   - `:Foo v:true v:true` gives `<v:true v:true,v:false>`, revealing that `<args>` is `'v:true v:true'`, while `two` uses the default.

Comment: See `:help <f-args>`.

Comment: @romainl, thanks. I understand now that the arguments passed to a command are always strings. As in, there's no `x` and `y` such that calling `:Foo x y` will call `s:foo(v:false, v:true)`. Am I correct? If not... can you explain?

Comment: From `:help :command-nargs`: "Note that arguments are used as text, not as expressions." Meaning that commands only see strings so they can only send strings to the underlying function.